# Compare two lists values and get unique values

Tags: apex, trigger

I have two lists

```
List<String> lst1 = new List<String>{'a','b','c','d'}; 
List<String> lst2 = new List<String>{'c','d','e','f','g','h'};
```

I need a list of Strings as below:

```
List<String> finallist = {'e','f','g','h'};
```

Compare two lists and remove values present in `lst1` of `lst2`
so I need final list as `{'e','f','g','h'}` as `'c'`,`'d'` are present in `lst1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Sets for this:

```
// Given
String[] list1 = new String[] { 'a','b','c','d' };
String[] list2 = new String[] { 'c','d','e','f','g','h' };
// Create a set for list2
Set<String> set1 = new Set<String>(list2);
// Remove anything from list1
set1.removeAll(list1);
// Convert back to list
String[] results = new List<String>(set1);
// Displaying results
System.debug(results); // {'e','f','g','h'}
```

Comment: 1 minute for answer O_O

Comment: Beat me to it with a better answer, Thanks for showing the usage of `removeAll` method!

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Actually, more like 3 minutes. I misread the question and had to fix my answer.

Comment: @Raul You're welcome! I love showing off language features, optimization is one of my favorite hobbies.